# Check shibboleth SP session on application level

Tags: security, single-sign-on, shibboleth, service-provider

The question may sound odd, but I have a worst case scenario.

My application server is on http://10.10.10.10/app (say it `app-server`) and http-apache server is on http://some.dns.com/app (say it `http-server`). Both are different system-server.

I know `app-server` shouldn't directly accessible publically, but let's assume it is publically accessible. Now `Shibboleth` is installed on `http-server` , securing path http://some.dns.com/app/secure . While one servlet is mapped to get attributes from path `/secure`.

If someone manages to create fake http-apache-server (say `fake-http-server`) and that too points to `app-server`. So here `fake-http-server` can directly have access to `/secure` path and that server can manually send shibboleth-like attributes and can login in system without protection.

My question here is, ***Is there a mechanism in Shibboleth where I can check the shibboleth session in my application - not only in http layer***.

Answer (score 1):

The mod_shib Apache module sets environment variables by default. These variables cannot be spoofed by a proxying Apache server.

From the [docs](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAttributeAccess):

> The safest mechanism, and the default for servers that allow for it,
>   is the use of environment variables. The term is somewhat generic
>   because environment variables don't necessarily always imply the
>   actual process environment in the traditional sense, since there's
>   often no separate process. It really refers to a set of controlled
>   data elements that the web server supplies to applications and that
>   cannot be manipulated in any way from outside the web server.
>   Specifically, the client has no say in them.

If you don't trust the Apache webserver, you can parse the SAML assertion in your code and validate the signatures in the assertion using the certificate provided by the Identity Provider (IdP) making the SAML assertion. But checking signatures is difficult and you need to deal with cases like key rotation and how to handle new certificates being used by the IdP. Shibboleth handles these very difficult and important tasks for you.